# Get Date from datetime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I have below code and I am getting below output:-
There are 5 days, 0:00:00 days between 2017-06-22 and 2017-06-27
But I just want:- **There are 5 days between 2017-06-22 and 2017-06-27**

Below is my code:-

```
from datetime import date
import random
earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))

days_between= later_date- earlier_date

print("There are", days_between, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to extract the number of days from the timedelta

```
days_between = (later_date - earlier_date).days

print("There are", days_between, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)

>>> There are 9 days between 2017-06-15 and 2017-06-24
```

The reason you can't get a date from a timedelta is because a timedelta represents a different between dates, rather than a date itself. It doesn't make sense to ask "What is the date of the number of days between March and May".

Comment: yes, it worked but when I tried to do same by using days_between=days_between.date But it did not work. can you guide me why it didn't work?

Comment: Do you mean `days_between.date` or `days_between.days`?

Comment: @Subham added an explanation to the answer

Comment: @Subham because timedelta is defined like this

`class datetime.timedelta([days,] [seconds,] [microseconds,] [milliseconds,] [minutes,] [hours,] [weeks])
`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.days`

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import date
import random
earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))

days_between= (later_date- earlier_date).days   #Update!

print("There are", days_between, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

Comment: Why you need `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d)` Seems already to work without.

Comment: @colidyre. Sorry I was using python2.7

Answer (score 2):

Operator `-` on `datetime` returns [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) . to get num days you can `.days` property

```
from datetime import date
import random
earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))

days_between= later_date- earlier_date
# days_between=days_between.date
print("There are", days_between.days, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

Comment: because timedelta is defined like this

`class datetime.timedelta([days,] [seconds,] [microseconds,] [milliseconds,] [minutes,] [hours,] [weeks])
`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
print("There are", days_between.days, "days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```